# using xargs with mv

Tags: command-line

So, I'm trying to move all screenshots files I found on my Desktop to a specific folder.

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Screenshot 2022-04-30 at 19.19.56.png
/Users/me/Desktop/Screenshot 2022-05-04 at 23.01.25.png
/Users/me/Desktop/Screenshot 2022-04-26 at 13.09.09.png
/Users/me/Desktop/Screenshot 2022-05-07 at 01.03.45.png
/Users/me/Desktop/Screenshot 2022-04-25 at 22.24.11.png
```

As the n00b I am, I am trying to run this series of commands:

`me@10 Desktop % find ~/Desktop | grep Scree | xargs -I mv '{}' ~/Pictures/Screenshots`

And I get `xargs: {}: No such file or directory`

How to achieve what I am looking for using `xargs`? (Other more efficient options are welcomed, but I am trying to learn and practise xargs.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: See from the Unix site https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90886/how-can-i-find-files-and-then-use-xargs-to-move-them

Comment: Thank you @mmmmmm! I followed the explanation on the link you posted, added `xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' ~/Pictures/Screenshots` and it worked; however, from the answer on the link, I am still not understanding why -I option requires '{}' twice, if it only needs to replace-str once per operation? I'm trying to wrap my head on `Implies -x and -L 1.` but still not getting it. Could you explain further? Thanks for always helping, I owe you big time!

Comment: I know that command line knowledge is its own reward, but.. showing a window of the Desktop in List or Column view, and selecting first through last, then dragging or copy - moving is arguably quicker than typing a lengthy xargs command. Particularly for a one-off action (presumably you have set your folder as the default location for screenshots now..?)

Comment: Hello @benwiggy! I totally agree with you; however, this is not the first time I find myself needing to act on several files that I need to comb through by means of CLI programs.  Also, I did not note this, but the amount of files listed on my example, is not a small bit of how much it is, can't be bothered to select them all, unselect others, etc.